# C# form press any key to continue

Tags: c#

I'm making an application for school and i would like to use the function 'press any key to continue' on the startup screen.

So when someone presses a key it opens te next form.
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Code so far:

```
//SOME ACTION//
   {
     Form2 f2 = new Form2();
     f2.Show();
     this.Hide();
   }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_events.aspx

Comment: Your question and code is no way related

Comment: use `Form.KeyPress` :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action you are looking for is the form's [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event, So you can handle `KeyPress` of your start screen form

```
 //you need to register the event handle to your form first.. 
 //so the following line could be in your start screen form's constructor  
 this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Form1_KeyPress); 

 //then you can open your new form as you suggested 
 void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
 {
     Form2 f2 = new Form2();
     f2.Show();
     this.Hide();
 }
```